# Account team, Opportunity access versus Opportunity team member

Tags: opportunity, access

I am trying to add a user to the account team and I provide Edit access on account and Edit access on Opportunity on the account team.
What would be the difference in doing this versus adding the user additionally to the Opportunity team? If they'd only need to edit the associated Opportunity, wouldn't it be sufficient to add access under account team and be done?

Basically, I'd want to understand the difference between Opportunity access under account team and Opportunity team itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that adding an Account Team Member with Opportunity Edit Access grants access to *every* Opportunity on the Account, while adding the Opportunity Team Member grants access only to that *specific* Opportunity. If there's only one Opportunity, there's no difference, of course, but if there are multiple Opportunity records on the Account, you might want to only grant access to just the one Opportunity.

Stated from a non-technical point of view, an Account Team Member helps manage the Account and all the Opportunities that the organization are doing with that Account, while an Opportunity Team Member is just doing a special, one-off Opportunity (perhaps because of its size, special requirements, area of expertise, etc), but are not otherwise normally involved with the Account.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for the answer. I have one question, if Account OWD is private and I add someone in the opportunity team with a read access to opportunity, will that expose the parent Account record to the newly added team member?

Comment: @AyushGoyal Yes. This is called "implicit sharing." Note that in this scenario, the user will be able to access only that one opportunity, and the account, but not other related opportunities or cases.

Comment: Thank you! One more follow up question - if implicit sharing is granting Read only access to Account record, will that expose related Contact records if sharing setting is not "Controlled by parent"? @sfdcfox

Comment: @AyushGoyal No, the contacts won't be shared without some sort of sharing set up explicitly on the account (e.g. Account Team Member).